# How to list videos that have been flagged for "Matched Third Party Content" using Python against YouTube API V3,

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api

I'm writing Python code (2.76) to access the YouTube API V3, search a given channel (authenticated with OAuth2.0), and return video details for items in that channel.  I'm able to get UniqueID, Position in Playlist, Title, Description, Keywords, Privacy Status, ViewCount, Published Date, # Likes, # Dislikes, # Comments, License, and Upload Status.

However, I'm not able to access whether a given video has been flagged for having "matched third party content" or not.  I suspect that it lies in *status.rejectionReason*.

Valid strings for *status.rejectionReason* are:

> "claim", "copyright", "duplicate", "inappropriate", "length",
>   "termsOfUse", "trademark", "uploaderAccountClosed", and
>   "uploaderAccountSuspended".

The description of *status.rejectionReason* states:

> "This value explains why YouTube rejected an uploaded video. This
>   property is only present if the *uploadStatus* property indicates that
>   the upload was rejected."

Valid strings for *status.uploadStatus* are:

> "deleted", "failed", "processed", "rejected", and "uploaded".

However, when looking at *status.uploadStatus* I see that the status actually is "processed" for videos that I know that have been flagged.  I suppose this makes sense as the videos are often uploaded and seem fine until they're flagged later for "Matched Third Party Content".

Occasionally, I can pull back a 'rejected' or 'failed' status but so far, the 'rejected' status only references a 'duplicate' upload and most times, the 'failed' status doesn't include a *status.failureReason*, which should only be

> "codec", "conversion", "emptyFile", "invalidFile", "tooSmall", or
>   "uploadAborted"

My question is:  Is there someplace else that I can look to see where 3rd party copyright flags are set?

This is affecting how we monetize videos.  I also don't know where to look to see if a video has been monetized or if its monetization attempt has been rejected.  Maybe this would be a better place to collect the information I'm looking for if it's possible.

Relevant sections of my code:

```
 # Call the API's videos.list method to retrieve the video resource.
 videos_list_response = youtube.videos().list(
   id=playlist_item["snippet"]["resourceId"]["videoId"],
   part="snippet,statistics,status"
   ).execute()

 if videos_list_response["items"][0]["status"]["uploadStatus"] == "failed":
   print videos_list_response["items"][0]["status"]
     try:
       WorkSheet.row(i).write(14,videos_list_response["items"][0]["status"]["failureReason"])
     except:
       WorkSheet.row(i).write(14,"Error on failureReason")

 if videos_list_response["items"][0]["status"]["uploadStatus"] == "rejected":
   print videos_list_response["items"][0]["status"]
     try:
       WorkSheet.row(i).write(14,videos_list_response["items"][0]["status"]["rejectionReason"])
     except:
       WorkSheet.row(i).write(14,"Error on rejectionReason")
```

Sample responses that I'm getting:

Rejected:

```
Getting video_id: jt0zTqTBid8  Index #765
{u'license': u'youtube', u'embeddable': True, u'privacyStatus': u'public', u'pub
licStatsViewable': True, u'uploadStatus': u'rejected', u'rejectionReason': u'dup
licate'}
```

Failed:

```
Getting video_id: 7ttiQfkl_K0  Index #837
{u'publicStatsViewable': True, u'privacyStatus': u'public', u'uploadStatus': u'f
ailed', u'license': u'youtube', u'embeddable': True}
```

I should mention that neither of the above videos were flagged for copyright.  The last one is just "failed".  The Video Manager page in YouTube says "aborted upload".  It has the Title, description, and other meta details, just no video.  However, the returned object doesn't have *status.failedReason* associated with it.